# How can I change the wire getRelatedListRecords to a util js?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

How can I make this wire method to a util method, instead of writing this code in each component?

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
        parentRecordId: '$accountId',
        relatedListId: 'test__r',
        where: "{ status : {eq: 'Completed'}}",
        fields: ['test__c.Id','test__c.status '],
        
    })listInfoPriorityRecords({ error, data }) {
        debugger;
        if (data) {
            console.log('::: records '+data.records);
            
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            //this.records = undefined;
        }
    }
```

I tried by creating an object of

```
let x = {
        parentRecordId: '$accountId',
        relatedListId: 'test__r',
        where: "{ status : {eq: 'Completed'}}",
        fields: ['test__c.Id','test__c.status '],
        
    }
@wire(getRelatedListRecords,x)listInfoPriorityRecords({ error, data }) {})
```

But It didn't worked

Is there any way to change this wire function to a utility method?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. With the way the LWC compiler works, wires must be part of a component. Could you make a component that renders "inline" as an empty span, for example, that your other components use, that fires a custom event containing the data when the data comes back through the wire?